# Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large, can't figure out why?

Tags: r

I am very new to R and was trying use plot function in R. Using R in linux environment

## Trying to plot data from a data frame named 'sample'

```
jpeg('rplot1.jpg')
plot(sample,cex=0.9,col="blue")
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
dev.off()
```

From what I understand I need to increase the size of the plot panel. Not sure how to do it.Tried

Comment: I tested your code on centOS (R 2.15.1) and MacOS GUI (R 2.15.0) and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: Thanks for testing. But I am not sure why this error is coming for me. I tested it in both red hat(R 2.15.1) and windows(R 2.15.2)

Answer (score 1):

You are giving a list (since dataframes are lists) to the `plot` function. Try instead:

```
plot(sample[[1]], sample[[2]], cex=0.9, col="blue")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, passing a `data.frame` with all numeric columns to the `plot` function is equivalent to calling `pairs` to plot the scatterplot matrix of all columns against each other. You probably know this.

As far as I can tell, the reason for the error is simply that the device (`jpeg`) is not large enough to sensibly contain the entire scatterplot matrix. For example,

```
mysamp <- matrix(rnorm(10000), nrow = 100)
mydat <- as.data.frame(mysamp)
plot(mydat)
# Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

In order to successfully create your plot, pass larger values to the `width` and `height` arguments of `jpeg`. Here's a function with an `hwFact` argument that should be a numeric value by which to multiply the height and width of your jpeg.

```
myFun <- function(data, hwFact = 1){
  jpeg("rplot1.jpg", width = 500 * hwFact, height = 500 * hwFact)
  plot(data, cex = .9, col = "blue")
  dev.off()
}
```

The following iteration uses the above function to successively increase `hwFact` until the jpeg is created. Once the jpeg is successfully created, the iteration number is printed and the iteration stops. (This will be pretty much the bare minimum size of the plot, which will most likely be too small to read anything.)

```
for(i in 1:20){
    res <- tryCatch(myFun(mydat, i), error = function(e) e)
    if(!"error" %in% class(res)) {
        print(i)
        break
    }
}
# [1] 3
```

So it took a jpeg with a width and height of 1500 (that's 500 * 3) to create a (completely illegible) plot. Once you know the minimum size, you'll have to experiment to find the appropriate size.